# Is there any SSL handshakes when trying to load https://localhost from browser on local machine?

Tags: ssl, localhost

I have Local Webserver that configured to use SSL connection.
The question is - would there be any handshakes if i try to open https://localhost from any browser?

The "classic" SSL handshake would require public keys and certs exchange on the network level to create Derive keys. But if we are trying to connect to local webserver, there would be no packets required for SSL handshake (Already tested with Wireshark).

So, does handshake really happens, but on the upper OSI level? Or it doesnt happen at all, and there are no derive key creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would there be any handshakes if i try to open https://localhost from any browser?

Yes,

> The "classic" SSL handshake would require public keys and certs exchange on the network level to create Derive keys.

No. It requires a certificate, and a premaster secret, and mutual negotiation of a master key from which session keys are derived. All this is irrelevant.

> But if we are trying to connect to local webserver, there would be no packets required for SSL handshake (Already tested with Wireshark).

Wireshark can't see loopback packets.

> So, does handshake really happens

Yes.

> but on the upper OSI level?

SSL happens in the application layer of the TCP model. The OSI model does not apply to TCP/IP. TCP/IP has its own model.

> Or it doesn't happen at all

It does.

> and there are no derive key creation?

There is creation of a pre-master secret, a master secret, and a session key. You seem to have some misconception of this process, but again it isn't relevant.